# Why does the complete wall fall over?

Tags: physics

Recently I bumped into the [Blender Fracture Modifier](http://df-vfx.de/fracturemodifier/). As this seems a very interesting "hidden treasure" I am now playing with it. I have installed the latest build for MACOS and I have made a setup where a wrecking ball should smash a wall. I made this very long wall .....

[image]

But after the wrecking ball hits the walll not only some shards are produced but the whole wall falls over. How to prevent this last things happening ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this blend, you need to adjust the following to get the desired effect:

1) set Rigidbody shape to Convex Hull, this is faster and with regular voronoi geometry, more stable as well. Means the wall will not explode with lower constraints settings.

2) reduce the constraint search radius to about 5.0 and the amount of constraints to 50. Those settings apply to each mesh island, means each island searches for max. 50 neighbors in a radius of 5.0 around its centroid then.
Rule of thumb: the smaller the shards are, the smaller the search radius can become to find enough neighbors. 
You dont need 2000 constraints per Island and such a large search radius here. (btw, I work without units mostly, but this is personal preference.)

3) optionally you could make the wall animated and triggered, and the wrecking ball a trigger. With this setting the shard simulation starts only for those shards being hit by a trigger, basically. The others remain inactive, which is faster too.

Comment: What exactly is a "mesh island" ?

Comment: well technically in the FM you got shards and mesh islands: Shards are the result of fracturing, while mesh islands manage the "look" of the simulation mesh. But here I used the term "mesh island" synonymously for each separate shard or piece of geometry the FM creates. So a mesh island = a piece of geometry whose vertices are moved as an unit according to motion data of the appropriate rigid body it belongs to.

Comment: If I do the adjustments as under 1) and 2) and also 3) ...so make the wall Triggered and the Wrecking Ball the Trigger and I also set the angle to zero it does not work. Only when I keep angle = 1 degree. It this correct ?

Comment: yup, angle zero means to ignore the breaking angle and rely only on breaking thresholds. the default threshold of 10 is way too strong for the default mass of 1 (where each shard gets assigned a fraction according to the fraction of the shards volume to the total volume (roughly)). So the special breaking conditions like angle, percentage or distance are there to let things break "easier".

Comment: I thought it as meant that when you make the wall triggered and the wrecking ball the trigger that the constraints are not of importance any more ?

Comment: should I lower the breaking treshold ?

Comment: constraints are there to glue the shards together in general. you can use triggering with or without them. But in simple cases of triggering, to achieve certain effects, you might as well omit the constraints, yes. But there are use cases to have constraints too (easily breakable ones together with clusters for example, to let for example collapse simulated geometry easier when it is hit (e.g. a building)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52856/discussion-between-scorpion81-and-old-man).